# Weka instance.setValue arrayIndexOutOfBounsException

Tags: java, weka

Good afternoon! I have such method:

```
private Instances getOneInstanceInstances(Map<String, Double> attributesMap) {
    FastVector fvWekaAttributes = new FastVector(attributesMap.size() + 1);

    for (String attributeName : attributesMap.keySet()) {
        Attribute attribute = new Attribute(attributeName);
        fvWekaAttributes.addElement(attribute);
    }

    FastVector fvClassVal = new FastVector(2);
    fvClassVal.addElement(Integer.toString(0));
    fvClassVal.addElement(Integer.toString(1));
    fvWekaAttributes.addElement(new Attribute("class", fvClassVal));

    Instances instances = new Instances("features", fvWekaAttributes,1);
    instances.setClassIndex(instances.attribute("class"));

    Instance instance = new Instance(fvWekaAttributes.capacity());
    instance.setDataset(instances);

    for (String attributeName : attributesMap.keySet()) {
        Attribute attribute = new Attribute(attributeName);
        instance.setValue(attribute, attributesMap.get(attributeName));;
    }

    instance.setClassMissing();
    instances.add(instance);    

    return instances;
}
```

And when I run it, it throw

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at weka.core.Instance.setValue(Instance.java:643)
at weka.core.Instance.setValue(Instance.java:716)
at uir.prunning.Prunner.getOneInstanceInstances(Prunner.java:189)
```

As I think, instance know everything about it's attributes, and everything looks ok for me, but it doesn't work. What's the problem and how can I fix it?
Thank you!